# macOS with APFS: Copy-On-Write in Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, copy-on-write, apfs

I am writing some little script that assembles backup data into one directory. The directory content will then be uploaded to a cloud service and after that we can remove it. I was wondering how one could utilize APFS' copy-on-write feature with a command like `cp` in Terminal.

The Finder does a great job. But if I run `cp Largefile LargeFileCopy` it takes forever to copy the file and also uses the space accordingly.

Answer (score 17):

I found it myself.

On macOS, `cp` supports the `-c` option. `cp -c Largefile LargeFileCopy` will then use the new clonefile(2) library and immediately return without using any additional space on the device.

Comment: **`cp` on macOS with APFS** —  Interesting that copy-on-write must be opted in with `-c` instead of being implicitly on as it is in the Finder. What were the design considerations behind this? Does anyone know?

Comment: May be it is meant to be POSIX compatible?

Comment: Seems a plausible answer.